# My tableview scrolling is very slow

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 

static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
MagazineListCell* cell=(MagazineListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil)
{
    NSArray *arr=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MagazineListCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    cell=(MagazineListCell *)[arr objectAtIndex:0];
    [cell setDelegate:self];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}

NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger startIndex;
NSInteger endIndex;

if(isLandscape)
{
    startIndex=indexPath.row*3;
    if (startIndex+3>[self.arrMagazine count ])
    {
        endIndex=[self.arrMagazine count];
    }
    else
    {
        endIndex=startIndex+3;
    }
}
else
{
    startIndex=indexPath.row*2;
    if (startIndex+2>[self.arrMagazine count])
    {
        endIndex=[self.arrMagazine count];
    }
    else
    {
        endIndex=startIndex+2;
    }
}
for (int x=startIndex; x<endIndex; x++)
{
    [arr addObject:[self.arrMagazine objectAtIndex:x]];
}
[cell setSelectedIndex:btnSegment.selectedSegmentIndex];
[cell contentForTableViewCell:arr setUIMode:isLandscape] ;
arr=nil;
return cell;

}
```

Comment: Have you done any profiling to find out what's taking the time?

Comment: Why ain't you keep your if-else condition code in willRotateToIntefaceOrientation method? Here it will unnecessarialy gets called each time when you reload table, even though its the same orientation.

Comment: it is not good idea to place your logic inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath,can I know how & when ur are going to access the data stored in cell ...

Answer (score 0):

Check that your reuse identifier is being set as you may be creating the cell every time.

The main problem is probably going to be the array you're creating every time, looping around to populate and then passing on to the cell. You should try to do all of that setup before you need it.

Comment: the looping is imp for myapp beacuse i have segment contrl and have to load table for every new view

Comment: @wain...i have done profileing and showing cell for row at index path the bugy one

Comment: And what did the profiling show, because that's the truth and what we're doing currently is educated guessing...